# Outlook 2016 Reminders in Mac Notifications

Tags: ms-office, notifications

Mac version: 10.11.6

Outlook for Mac version: 15.26.1

I have reminders as a separate app, but I would like show them in native Mac notifications (i.e coming from top right corner) How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you mean you have Reminders as a seperate app? It's build in Outlook right?

Comment: One option is to load up your agenda in the Calendar app, that will show notifications on the top right of MacOS